# how can I get all users list using instagram Api

Tags: instagram-api

I am trying to use Instagram API to create all users information.I need to get all instagram user list and their related information.  Can you help me please? How can I find this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the Instagram API documentation? What coding language are you using?

Comment: I am using c# language. I have gone through api  documentation but unable to find any appropriate solution for this.

Comment: You're looking to pull back a list of all Instagram users?

Comment: Yes. List of all instagram users.

Comment: Is that possible or not?

Comment: Absolutely not! The data returned would be huge